# Find the inverse Laplace transform of $L(s)= \frac{s}{s^2 + 25} e^{-\pi s}$

Tags: laplace-transform

$$L(s)= \frac{s}{s^2 + 25} e^{-\pi s}$$

I never seen such function. Can exponential function appear in Laplace transform?

Help required

Comment: Do you know anything about step functions?

Comment: No.. I know there is a convolution theorem or something

Comment: I recommend watching this good lecture on the topic: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03-differential-equations-spring-2010/video-lectures/lecture-22-using-laplace-transform-to-solve-odes-with-discontinuous-inputs/

Comment: Thank you... I skip that chapter.. That's y confusion. So the question is straightforward, right.. I mean easy?

Comment: So the answer is what cos(t-pi) * u(t-π) please confirm

Comment: @JeanMarie That is incorrect

Comment: @Simon S Yes, I understand my error : in this backward sense it is a shift. So user69468 you were right

Comment: @JeanMarie I don't think so. I've written an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were close (in the comments), but in fact, with $\;\mathcal L\{f(t)\}=F(s)\;$:

$$\mathcal L^{-1}\left\{e^{-cs}F(s)\right\}= u_c(t)f(t-c)\implies\mathcal L^{-1}\left\{e^{-\pi s}\frac s{s^2+25}\right\}=u_\pi(t) \cos(5(t-\pi))=$$

$$=-u_\pi(t)\cos 5t$$

Comment: Yes. Just to clarify: where

$$u_c(t) = u(t - c)$$

Comment: Thank you very much @SimonS : yes, indeed both notations are used, though I use more the subindexed one.

Comment: Thank you Simon S, and @Joanpemo .